# Problems communicating between Apache Solr and Magento Enterprise - only "pings" in the Solr log

Tags: php, apache, magento, solr

I recently set up an Apache Solr 1.4.1 server to work with Magento Enterprise 1.9.

The setup seems to work fine, and Magento reports that it can successfully conntect to Solr.

I can perform Solr queries within the Solr interface and it seems like the Magento data has been successfully indexed by Solr.

However... when I search via Magento, it seems that it's not actually taking the search results from Solr but instead getting them as usual from Magento's MySQL database.

This shouldn't happen as the Catalog Search engine is definitely set to Solr within Magento.

When I run a query via the Solr admin interface, the Solr log file shows this:

`[09/05/2013:05:54:48 +0000] "GET /solr/select/?q=fulltext1_en%3Ashirt&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on HTTP/1.1" 200 33594`

When I search via my Magento store, I just get this:

`[09/05/2013:05:54:32 +0000] "HEAD /solr/admin/ping HTTP/1.0" 200 0`

So to me, it seems like Magento is just "pinging" Solr but not actually sending the query data.

I've enabled `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini to rule that out.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check the file `var/log/exception.log` for entries.

Assuming the `ping` you see in the Solr logs is the ping executed by the proper class, i.e.

```
Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_HttpStream::_search()    // or
Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_PhpExtension::_search()
```

you should find log entries if something failed after the ping, since the `catch` statement logs.